# Display data from MS SQL using Android Application

Tags: android, sql-server, android-studio

I already created a ConnectionClass.java where the server name, database and others are set but my problem is on the MainActivity.java how can i display data from sql server which i have the table name "TableStatus" and the rows are TableName, TransactionNumber and Status

here is my source code for MainAcitivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ConnectionClass connectionClass;
ListView lstpro;
String proid;
String z = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    lstpro = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstproducts);

}

// View ?

public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String z = "";

    List<Map<String, String>> prolist  = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String[] from = { "A", "B", "C" };
        int[] views = { R.id.lblproid, R.id.lblproname,R.id.lblprodesc };
        final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                prolist, R.layout.lsttemplate, from,
                views);
        lstpro.setAdapter(ADA);


        lstpro.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) ADA
                        .getItem(arg2);
                proid = (String) obj.get("A");
                String proname = (String) obj.get("B");
                String prodesc = (String) obj.get("C");
                //edtprodesc.setText(prodesc);
               // edtproname.setText(proname);
                //     qty.setText(qtys);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
            } else {
                String query = "select * from TableStatus";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    datanum.put("A", rs.getString("TableID"));
                    datanum.put("B", rs.getString("TableName"));
                    datanum.put("C", rs.getString("Status"));
                    prolist.add(datanum);
                }
                z = "Success";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            z = "Error retrieving data from table";

        }
        return z;
    }

 }
}
```

Any help will do beginner on android development

Comment: have you try any code then please add it too.

Comment: @mark.bendal.erica Plz first make webservice after try this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: have you able to connect successfully with db.

Comment: I added the source code any kind of idea and help will do

Answer (score 0):

`DBconnection.Getconnection()` explanation here [**Connection Demo**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477837/failed-to-remote-server-sql-server-using-jdts/38477975#38477975)

```
private void DBSyncData() {

        try {
            Connection connect = DBconnection.Getconnection();
            Statement cat = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet category = cat.executeQuery("Select * from TableStatus");

            while (category.next()) {

                String col1 = category.getString("ColumName1"));
                String col2 = category.getString("ColumName2"));
                //....

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

**Update:**

My working code **Note** i am using older version of jar `jtds 1.2.7` file having issue with latest version.

```
public class DBconnection {

    public static String User_name = "saxxxx";
    public static String User_pass = "xxxxxh";
    public static String Db_name = "xxxxx";
    static Context mcontext;
    public static Connection Conn = null;
    public static String Server_ip = "192.168.5.14:1433;";

    public static Connection Getconnection() {

        Log.i("Android", " MySQL Connect.");
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        String connString = null;
        try {
            Log.i("SQL Looking", "Start Looking for server");
            String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + Server_ip
                    + ";databaseName=" + Db_name + ";user=" + User_name
                    + ";password=" + User_pass + ";";

            Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
            Log.i("Connection", "open DB Class");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mcontext, e.toString() + "db", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Log.w("Error connection", e.getMessage());

        }
        return Conn;
    }

    public static void close_DB() {

        try {
            Conn.close();
            Log.i("Connection", "Close DB Class");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```